# How do I test that every line throws the same exception?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I want to test that my function refuses all non-positive integers. It throws an InvalidArgumentException. I wrote a test like this:

```
/**
 * @test
 * @expectedException InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function testXThrowsException()
{
    $this->parser->x(1.5);
    $this->parser->x('2');
    $this->parser->x(1000E-1);
    $this->parser->x(+100);
}
```

My test always passes because the first one throws an exception. The others don't get tested properly. I can add `$this->parser->x(1);` to my code and it would still pass.

What should I do to assert that all these function calls raise the InvalidArgumentException?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
 * @test
 * @expectedException InvalidArgumentException
 *
 * @dataProvider foo
 */
public function testXThrowsException($value)
{
    $this->parser->x($value);
}

/**
 * Test data
 * Returns array of arrays, each inner array is used in
 * a call_user_func_array (or similar) construction
 */
public function foo()
{
    return array(
        array(1.5),
        array('2'),
        array(1000E-1),
        array(+100)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to use it like this:

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function testXThrowsException()
{
    try {
        $this->parser->x(1.5);
        $this->fail('message');
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {}
    try {
        $this->parser->x('2');
        $this->fail('message');
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {}
    try {
        $this->parser->x(1000E-1);
        $this->fail('message');
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {}
    try {
        $this->parser->x(+100);
        $this->fail('message');
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {}

}
```

Now you can test every line on its own. Whenever method `x()` does *not* raise an exception, the test fails using `fail()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have alot of negative values you could also put them in an array, and loop over the array with the following code (without testing):

```
foreach($wrongValueArray as $failtyValue) { 
  try { $this->parser->x($failtyValue); 
      this->fail($failtyValue . ' was correct while it should not'); 
  } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {} 
}
```

It's a bit shorter